# Which wordpress hook call theme update on progress with the theme name?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to get the detail of theme which I update whether it is activated or deactivated. How can we use a hook when Theme is updating and return the theme name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Wp_Upgrader class instance [as explained here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/upgrader_process_complete) and it can be instance of [theme upgrader](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/theme_upgrader/). You can use something like wordpress init to look at if you are worried that other people can access the admin page for upgrades and you want to stop them from doing so. I am not sure the actual purpose you want this for but it is possible to inject into core upgrade process to do something like upgrade plugin or theme. Read around [Theme_Upgrade](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/theme_upgrader/upgrade/). You can also use something like [pre_auto_update](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_auto_update/) hook to cover for theme update, I have not used it but I think this might be quick way to check all theme or your theme auto update running or you can hook further into when [update data](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_update_data/) is fetched.